# can I create a provider that will return a new object each time get is called

Tags: java, guice, provider

I want to have a provider member in class, that when 'get' called will give me a new object each time. how can I do that?

```
public class GuiceInjectionTest
{
  @Inject
  Provider<MyClass> provider;

  public Provider<MyClass> get()
  {
    //I want a new instance every time here that is injected by guice
    return provider.get() 
  }
}
```

Note I want this new instance to be injected by Guice, so I cant just create a `new MyClass()` in the provider implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While @GuillaumePolet's solution will work, it's not quite the preferred way to do this. Binding `MyClass` is correct, but you shouldn't inject the `Injector` for this (you should avoid injecting the `Injector` in general).

For any type you can inject, Guice can automatically inject a `Provider` of that type. So what you should do is this:

```
@Inject
Provider<MyClass> provider;

...
return provider.get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your provider with the following code:

```
bind(MyClass.class).toProvider(MyClassProvider.class);
```

In your provider, you can inject the Injector and request a new instance MyClass.class

```
@Inject
Injector injector;

...
return injector.newInstance(MyClass.class);
```

But you can also simply bind your class with:

```
bind(MyClass.class);
```

to have the same result (not exactly, depending on how you use your provider)